# Sending image in base64 with SOAP in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, uiimage

I am a newbie in iOS development. I am trying to send a clicked image by encoding it into base64 format using SOAP. I don't know how to do this.

This is my imagePickerController delegate:

```
  // delegate method for picking images
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
  {
     NSString *mediaType = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage])
   {
    UIImage *photoTaken = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    //Save Photo to library only if it wasnt already saved i.e. its just been taken
     if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) 
      {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photoTaken, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

     NSData *data=[[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(photoTaken)];
        base64= [[NSString alloc]init];
        base64 =[data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];    
      }
    }

//   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: base64 is string type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo..

```
 UIImage* chosenImage =info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

//encoding image to base64

    imgData=[[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage)];
_base64=[[NSString alloc]init];

    _base64=[imgData  base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
self.tempbase= _base64;
```

and calling tempbase in soap message

Answer (score 0):

The image size will be huge. It can reduce your app performance hence decrase the image size first by resizing the image.

```
-(UIImage *) imageWithImage:(UIImage *) image scaledTOSize:(CGSize) newsize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newsize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newsize.width, newsize.height)];
    UIImage *newImg=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImg;
}
```

Now convert this small sized `UIImage` into `NSData`

```
 NSData *imgData=[[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

Then convert `NSData` into base64 string using third party library -

> base64.h
>
> NSData+Base64.h

```
NSstring *imgString = [imgData base64EncodedString];
imgString = [imgString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now send this string to your services.

Comment: maam,its not working..error is [CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xbbf6000

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.frame.size);
[self.drawImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *imageView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView, 1.0f);
[Base64 initialize];
NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
```

NOTE: drawImage is object of UIImageView and Import Base64.h class.